# NPM Install Global stuck

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

when i try to install angular cli in my computer i keep stuck on

```
loadRequestedDeps ->netw | #######---------------------------------
```

and not going any where , as long as im waiting ,

i'm running the command prompt in administrator already

and i'm already try this step

```
npm uninstall -g angular-cli
npm cache clean
npm install -g angular-cli@latest
```

last time im install angular-cli: 1.0.0-beta.6
is working fine but now i cant install any npm in global, but i can install it from package.json

Comment: Did you check your Internet connection? This happens with me when my Internet disconnected.

Comment: it is connected, did i got block or something? how to check that? you have any idea?